# http://example.com would not redirect to https://www.example.com

Tags: apache, redirect

we have this two conf on our webserver.

http:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.de
    ServerAlias example.de www.example.at example.at www.example.net example.net

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
   # Error page is just the index telling about the situation of not being connected
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

https:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.de
    ServerAlias example.de www.example.at example.at www.example.net example.net

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.de/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.de/privkey.pem

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

    DocumentRoot /var/www/homepage/web
    <Directory /var/www/homepage/web>
            AllowOverride All
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>



            ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-ssl.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-ssl.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I try to open http://www.example.com then it would be redirect to https://www.example.com

When I try to open http://example.com or https://example.com, then I got the error "Page not available"

What is wrong in my both conf-Files on the Webserver? 
Both should redirected to the https://www.example.com url.

Comment: No, HTTP_HOST is not going to contain the value `off` ... not unless you are trying to access `http://off`

Comment: Where should I add this HTTP_HOST that I can set it to off?

Comment: Why not configuring the apache vhosts with no redirection and doing the redirection from an .htaccess file?

Comment: I thought, that it would be easier in the Apache conf

Comment: _“Where should I add this HTTP_HOST that I can set it to off?”_ – nowhere, because that does not even make sense. You are accessing the wrong variable here. You want to check the `HTTPS` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try to avoid mod_rewrite unless there is no other option. As you can see it's complicated and will make your life harder for the simpler tasks.

A single Redirect will do to redirect everything to the SSL virtualhost:

```
Redirect / https://www.example.de/
```

Note: Redirect depends on mod_alias, so no need to RewriteEngine on or such either in the non-SSL virtualhost.

---

If you insist on using mod_rewrite because you have many names and need the variables:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

The first one catches those cases where host does not start with www, the second catches the rest.

Comment: Sorry, but this don't solve the problem, that http://example.com and https://example.com  get redirected to https://www.example.com. this would also view "Website not available. Subdomains are available like https://app.example.com or https://partner.example.com. This subdomains would have a other directory on the server.

Comment: @MiracleJohnson added mod_rewrite example for what you describe.